# how to create an address or wallet in several tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Hello community I am using nodejs and web3, I would like to know if it is possible to create an address in each token and then bring the corresponding balance of each token

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how Ethereum ERC-20 tokens work.

A single Ethereum account (address) can serve multiple tokens. There is no need to create a separate address for each token.

To get an ERC-20 balance of an address for an token is well documented. For example. follow this [ERC-20 tutorial](https://medium.com/@piyopiyo/how-to-get-erc20-token-balance-with-web3-js-206df52f2561).